# Unexpected automatic re-start after update installation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-update

I had a bit of an unexpected event this afternoon. A Windows Server 2012 R2 terminal server rebooted itself unexpectedly after an update installation, contrary to the settings set in the Group Policy.

The following GPO applies to the server:

```
Windows Update 
Data collected on: 2016-12-19 16:23:58

General
Details
Domain xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.net 
Owner XXXX\Domain Admins 
Created 2016-11-15 13:36:44 
Modified 2016-11-15 13:39:40 
User Revisions 0 (AD), 0 (SYSVOL) 
Computer Revisions 5 (AD), 5 (SYSVOL) 
Unique ID {91ADBD9A-8488-4F98-B04A-9C8029A437B2} 
GPO Status Enabled 

Links
Location Enforced Link Status Path 
xxxx No Enabled xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.net 

This list only includes links in the domain of the GPO.
Security Filtering
The settings in this GPO can only apply to the following groups, users, and computers:Name 
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users 

Delegation
These groups and users have the specified permission for this GPOName Allowed Permissions Inherited 
XXXX\Domain Admins Edit settings, delete, modify security No 
XXXX\Domain Computers Read No 
XXXX\Enterprise Admins Edit settings, delete, modify security No 
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Read (from Security Filtering) No 
NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS Read No 
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Edit settings, delete, modify security No 

Computer Configuration (Enabled)
Policies
Administrative Templates
Policy definitions (ADMX files) retrieved from the central store.Windows Components/Windows Update
Policy Setting Comment 
Allow Automatic Updates immediate installation Enabled  
Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications Disabled  
Always automatically restart at the scheduled time Enabled  
The restart timer will give users 
this much time to save their 
work (minutes):  15 

Policy Setting Comment 
Configure Automatic Updates Enabled  
Configure automatic updating: 4 - Auto download and schedule the install 
The following settings are only required and applicable if 4 is selected. 
Install during automatic maintenance Disabled 
Scheduled install day:  0 - Every day 
Scheduled install time: 03:00 

Policy Setting Comment 
Turn on recommended updates via Automatic Updates Enabled  

User Configuration (Enabled)
No settings defined.
```

The expected result therefore should be that the server should install any updates with no impact immediately, and install any updates not requiring any reboot at 3 AM, after which it will reboot.

The actual result is that the server rebooted at 16:51:30 with the following message in WindowsUpdate.log:

```
2017-01-11  16:51:30:071     812    1368    AU  Client has determined it is safe to reboot without warning. Rebooting now...
```

By using the TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager log I have been able to determine that the last user of the terminal server logged off for the day at 16:41:29, so it would seem that after exactly 10 minutes of nobody being logged onto the computer, the machine did reboot. The full [WindowsUpdate.log](http://www.pvz.pp.se/WindowsUpdate.log-Serverfault-20170111.txt) is available for review.

Further analysis of the log does seem to indicate that updates that required reboots were installed at 03.00 at 2017-01-11 as per the setting, but for some undetermined reason, the server was not rebooted at that time.

Comment: Did someone set a deadline for an update in the WSUS server?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart We do not use a WSUS server, the server is configured to use Windows Update directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user logged in for a few days, and the server installs updates during its normal updated schedule, updates that require a reboot will not kick off the reboot until the last user logs out.

So if your user logged in yesterday, disconnected or left their session open, then the updates installed at 3AM, the machine wants to reboot but won't until the last user logs out, so if the logged out at 16:41, the server sees that its safe and initiates the reboot.

Comment: I am aware of this default behavior. The setting "Always automatically restart at the scheduled time" has been enabled to counter this. Monitoring data does seem to support the fact that a user was logged in overnight, though. Despite this setting, reboot still did not happen at that time.   Some details on that setting are here but does not seem to work as advertised. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wsus/2013/10/08/enabling-a-more-predictable-windows-update-experience-for-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-kb-2885694/